# Firestore authorization: cloud-functions vs Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, authorization, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I thought about moving most of my logic to cloud-code functions, and handle the authorization parts there instead of Cloud Firestore Security Rules ?

I'm still not sure what is the best solution for that, but I can say that it seems like it is more easy to create an authorization middleware using cloud-code functions, and not using firestore.rules.

I was able to achieve very simple authorization rules using firestore.rules, and combining the two seems like an overhead.

Any thoughts or recommendations would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c

Answer (score 0):

> it is more easy to create an authorization middleware using cloud-code functions, and not using firestore.rules.

You don't need to invent anything. There are already software solutions that do just that. It's called attribute-based access control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)) and there are frameworks e.g. AuthZForce or [Axiomatics](https://www.axiomatics.com) that provide:

- a policy language (XACML or ALFA)
- a Policy Decision Point (PDP)
- an interceptor framework (sometimes called a Policy Enforcement Point or PEP).

Comment: Thanks David ! I will check your solution and will update.